# Add in ArrayList<Integer> takes too long (more than 50000 nodes)

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to create a search engine which is based on IR systems. So, I have some files, I take the information I need and I store them in structures such as HashMaps, TreeMaps, ArrayLists e.t.c. Then, I want to write this information in files. So, I open at the same time 2 FileWriters. But I add in them more and more strings.

But this procedure takes too long. I don't know why. When I put everything in the FileWriter, I close it through `close()`.

Do you think that the problem is the reallocation every time I add new strings in my buffers?

Should I follow another strategy of opening the buffer, write, close it, and the next time open again to write at the end of the previous data? This will take less in time?

P.S.: The code is working exactly as i want for a small input file. The problem is when i use large and many input files.

```
public static void writeWordsandDfInFile(Map<String, Word> tmpMap) throws IOException
{
    Set tmpSet = tmpMap.entrySet();//Transform to Set for quick iteration  and printing
    Iterator tmpIt = tmpSet.iterator();
    String le3h=null;
    int bytesPostingFile;
    int bytesVocabularyFile;
    String str_out = null;
    String prev_str_out = null;
    String str_out2 = null;
    String str_tmp;
    String str_tmp2;
    String Tstrt;
    int prevctr=0;
    int flag=0;
    int i=0;
    int j;
    int k;
    int flag2;
    int flag3;
    int docId;
    //////////////////
    int SIZEDocumentsFileBytes;
    int prevInDocumentsFileBytes = 0;
    int newInDocumentsFileBytes = 0;
    int prwth_kataxwrhsh;
    int ctrPostingFileBytes=0;
    int prwthMonofora=0;



    giveWrdTakeBytePos=new HashMap<String,Integer>();//8a t dinw thn le3h kai 8a mou epistrefei thn 8esh se bytes mesa sto VocabularyFile.txt

    // Create file
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(vocabularyFile.getPath());
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.
    out.write("Le3h   Df   PosInPostingFile.txt\n\n");
    str_tmp=("Le3h   Df   PosInPostingFile.txt\n\n");

      // Create file
    FileWriter fstream2 = new FileWriter(postingFile.getPath());
    BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(fstream2);
    out2.write("DocId  Tf  LineInFile       PosInDocumentsFile\n\n");
    str_tmp2=("DocId  Tf  LineInFile       PosInDocumentsFile\n\n");



    PostingFileBytes=new ArrayList<Integer>();//krataw ta bytes gia kaue eggrafh sto PostingFile



    flag=0;
    i=0;
    while(tmpIt.hasNext())
    {

         Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) tmpIt.next();
         le3h=(String)m.getKey();

         Set s = tmpMap.get(le3h).getDocList().entrySet();
         Iterator it = s.iterator();
         Map.Entry mm =(Map.Entry)it.next();
         docId=(Integer)mm.getKey();


         Set ss=tmpMap.get(le3h).getDocList().keySet();

         Set stf=tmpMap.get(le3h).getTf().keySet();

         Iterator ssIt = ss.iterator();




         flag2=0;
         prwth_kataxwrhsh=0;
         while(ssIt.hasNext())
         {
            docId=(Integer)ssIt.next();

            out2.write(docId+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getTf(docId));//grafw sto VocabularyFile.txt thn ka8e le3h kai to Df ths
            if(flag2==0)
            {
                str_out2=(docId+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getTf(docId));
                flag2=1;
            }
            else
            {
                str_out2=(docId+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getTf(docId));
            }



            flag3=0;
            Tstrt=null;
            for(k=0;k<tmpMap.get(le3h).ByteList.get(docId).size();k++)
            {
                out2.write("  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).ByteList.get(docId).get(k));

                if(flag3==0)
                {
                    Tstrt=("  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).ByteList.get(docId).get(k));
                    flag3=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Tstrt=Tstrt+("  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).ByteList.get(docId).get(k));
                }

            }
            str_out2=str_out2+Tstrt;
            out2.write("  ->"+DocumentsFileBytes.get(docId)+"\n");
            str_out2=str_out2+("  ->"+DocumentsFileBytes.get(docId)+"\n");
            bytesPostingFile=str_out2.toString().length();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



            //................................................................................................................................
          SIZEDocumentsFileBytes=PostingFileBytes.size();

          if(prwthMonofora==0)
          {
            prevInDocumentsFileBytes=str_tmp2.toString().length();

            prwthMonofora=1;

            PostingFileBytes.add(prevInDocumentsFileBytes);
            ctrPostingFileBytes=0;//dld. parxei kataxwrish sthn 8esh 0 tou posting file
            newInDocumentsFileBytes=prevInDocumentsFileBytes + bytesPostingFile;
            //System.out.println("EPOMENH: "+newInDocumentsFileBytes);
          }
          else
          {
              if(prwth_kataxwrhsh==0)//gia ka8e le3h mono thn prwth fora kai as exei DF>1
              {
                    //System.out.println("Prohg. Timh:"+prevInDocumentsFileBytes);
                    prevInDocumentsFileBytes=newInDocumentsFileBytes;//apo prin
                    //System.out.println("BAZW: "+prevInDocumentsFileBytes);
                    PostingFileBytes.add(prevInDocumentsFileBytes);
                    ctrPostingFileBytes++;
                    prwth_kataxwrhsh=1;
              }
              else
              {
                prevInDocumentsFileBytes=newInDocumentsFileBytes;
              }
              newInDocumentsFileBytes=prevInDocumentsFileBytes + bytesPostingFile;
              //System.out.println("EPOMENH: "+newInDocumentsFileBytes);
          }


         }


         //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


         int ptr=ctrPostingFileBytes;

         out.write(le3h+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getDf());//grafw sto VocabularyFile.txt thn ka8e le3h kai to Df ths

         out.write("  ->"+PostingFileBytes.get(ptr)+"\n");


           if(flag==0)//thn prwth fora
            {
               str_out=(le3h+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getDf()+"  ->"+PostingFileBytes.get(ptr)+"\n");
               giveWrdTakeBytePos.put(le3h, str_tmp.toString().length());
               flag=1;
               prev_str_out=str_tmp+str_out;
            }
            else
            {
                giveWrdTakeBytePos.put(le3h, prev_str_out.toString().length());

                str_out=str_out+(le3h+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getDf()+"  ->"+PostingFileBytes.get(ptr)+"\n");
                prev_str_out=prev_str_out+(le3h+"  "+tmpMap.get(le3h).getDf()+"  ->"+PostingFileBytes.get(ptr)+"\n");
            }

      //................................................................................................................................


    }

    //Close the output stream
    out.close();

    //Close the output stream
    out2.close();

}
```

Comment: could you state what you mean by 'large'? and how long does it take (how long do you expect it to?) And: how fast is the HD you are writing to?

Comment: you could try to add out1.flush(); out2.flush(); at the end of your loop and see if that changes anything.

Comment: In the future you should pair down your code example.  Having to wade through all of your code to focus on the problem is not helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your advice adding flush() at the end of loops.

Comment: I put flush() but the problem remains. Actually, to help you understand, i keep an ArrayList<Integer> PostingFileBytes in which i keep the positions of each entry in a file named as PostingFile. Later, i want to use random access files to seek the entry i want. So, i don't know why, but the delay is either when i put the entries in that ArryList or when i read from the ArryList the entries.

Comment: @limas I'm currently reading through your code. Would you be so kind to translate your comments into english? I couldn't even guess what language it is to try an automated translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see you never append to a file but always write it new. But from what you wrote above (without having read the whole code) you want to append Data to the file.

```
new FileWriter("path", true);
```

Does that help you?

Another suggestion drop the File write and use this:

```
public static void foo()
{
    // ...

    byte[] fifeMBByteAryOne = new byte[5242880];
    ByteArrayStream bStream = new ByteArrayStream(fifeMBByteAryOne);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bStream));
    byte[] fifeMBByteAryTwo = new byte[5242880];
    ByteArrayStream bStream2 = new ByteArrayStream(fifeMBByteAryTwo);
    BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bStream2));

    // ...

}

private static class ByteArrayStream extends OutputStream {
    int index = 0;
    byte[] container;

    public ByteArrayStream(byte[] container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        container[index++] = (byte)b;
    }

}
```

Then let it run again and see how long it takes. If it is as slow as before, the File is not your problem.

---

After having read through the code, I'm fairly sure that you are a student or beginner in java programming, that's fine, but you should have stated that in your question. Also it causes people to give you advices rather than direct solutions to your problem.

There are a lot of things you could improve.
The first and from my point of view very important: You coding style needs improvement. Really! There are standards on how you write variables (starting with a small letter) methods and so on. Use them. You use far more variables than you need and you define them all at the beginning of the method.
You use Sets and Iterators when you don't need them (e.G.

```
Set s = currentWord.getDocList().entrySet();
Iterator it = s.iterator();
Map.Entry mm = (Map.Entry) it.next();
docId = (Integer) mm.getKey();
```

then you never use the value of docId, but of course this action here takes time.

Rewrite that method and this time understand what you do and do only what you need, when you need it, the way it is now I would not allow anyone in my company to use it for a customer.

Second: when you post code to the internet be sure to post code that compiles directly. I needed 15 Minutes to have that code compiling. There are very few people around that have that much patience.

Third: For Situations were you write less than ~ 2MB of text its usually useful to use a StringBuilder to construct the whole text and to write it as one thing in the end. That makes debugging easier.

Fourth: Before you post code on the internet be sure to have thought about the problem yourself and have tested to solve it. In this case you could use Dates to do so, just write a text like:

```
// at the beginning of a loop
long startedAt = new Date().getTime();
// somewhen within the loop:
System.out.println("in situation X " + (new Date().getTime()-startedAt);
```

That way you can see what step takes how long and can then start to optimize that area.

Fifth: If after Fourth there is still a problem be sure to post a short piece of code that demonstrates clearly your problem. Don't rely on the other users to understand your problem, show it to them. Make it easy for them by using self explaining variable-, method-, classnames in the language you are asking. Same goes for your comments.

Sixth: The reason you should do all this is to give you the ability to solve your problems yourself and to ask people with extended skills only the problems that are worth their time.

Good luck

Comment: I just open each of 2 FileWriters(and bufferwriters) and then i write in them all the time.. I close them when i am done with reading the info from my structures saved in main memory. I tried to change the default size of the bufferwriters, i put a very large one, but the problem remains. So, i think the problem is somewhere else. Does the buffer reallocate itself when is full??? Or should i open the buffer, write on it, close it and then open again when i need?? If i use this strategy, i definetly use the code you wrote to me above(the parameter "true" for appending)

Comment: @limas Its tricky to tell from here. You should find out what part exactly is slow: Is it the 'write the bits to the disk' part or is it the 'read the data from the structure' and what does 'slow' mean? Is it rocket fast but you want lightning fast or is it incredibly not-useable slow? If you would give some numbers it would help. (e.G. I write 10 GB of data and it takes 20 Seconds but I want it done in 5 Seconds)

Comment: @limas BufferedWriter does not speed up the whole writing process, but speeds up situations where short bursts of data are being written and then nothing for a while. You write a pretty constant datastream so I would not assume that increasing the BufferedWriter buffer would do you any good.

Comment: Thank's for your advice. I want to be done with the indexing part(writing in data structures and then in files) the most in 2 minutes. The files'size is: 13 Mb. Now it takes 36 minutes :-(

Comment: @limas I added another suggestion, would you please try it and tell me how long it takes then?

Comment: Could you explain me what should i change in my code, please?? Could you give any directions??

Comment: @limas look in my answer. My current idea is that its not the file thats slow but your handling of data. This can have many many many reasons so we have to sort them out one by one. First is: you replace your file with a byte array. The example I wrote in my answer above uses 5MB for each of the byte[] that you shall use instead of files. So you keep your BufferedWriter the way it is and everything stays the same EXECEPT that you write to memory instead on the disk. If it is still slow we have to search further.

Comment: So, i just add your code in mine and i change this line for instance: FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(vocabularyFile.getPath()); and i put fifeMBByteAryOne instead of vocabularyFile.getPath(). In other words: FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fifeMBByteAryOne); And i do the same for the other file, right?? Should i call foo() somewhere?? Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: @limas No, don't use the FileWriter either. Use the OutputStreamWriter as in my example.

Comment: I put in comments the lines: FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(vocabularyFile.getPath()); 
and 
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 

and 
FileWriter fstream2 = new FileWriter(postingFile.getPath());
and
BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(fstream2);



Then , i call foo(),just down this line:  
giveWrdTakeBytePos=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

I let it run, but the delay still remains. Also, the array size we put is smaller than the entries. In the previous run, i saw the size of my ArrayList to be ~50000. So it has 50000 nodes.

Comment: @limas okay, so if the delay remains its obviously not the FileWriter thats causing the delay. I'll go sleep now (its past midnight here) and have a look tomorrow again. You might want to change your question (title etc.) to reflect the gained information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to follow your advice. Thank's for your time. 
P.S.: The code is compiling. I never post code with syntax or other errors.

Comment: @limas the code may be compiling for you. But for every person who does not have the class 'Word' it will not compile.